# I created an Android application with two activities, but cannot switch back from the second activity to the first

Tags: android, android-layout, button, onactivityresult

I created an Android application with two activities, but somehow the buttons on the second activity do not seem to work properly.  The button on the first activity (a map activity and a button to add infromat which takes users to the second activity with an information entry screen) works fine, neither button on the second activity seems to have any effect... I can't even get an OnClick Toast message to work.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback , LocationListener {

   public void AddMapInfo(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InformationInputActivity.class);
    LatLng providedLocation = current;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("provided_location", providedLocation);
    intent.putExtra("bundle", args);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    Toast.makeText(this, "back with cheese!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (requestCode != 1){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Oops... This shouldn't happen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else{

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        InformationPoint informationPoint = (InformationPoint) data.getSerializableExtra("information_point");

        informationPoint.display(mymap);

    }

}


}
```

The second activity brings on the layout for the screen, and it sets the proper options for the EditText field, so I know it gets control... but that's about it.  There is no Toast message from any of the methods (I still get the Toasts when the location update info is received on the first activity instead), and neither the radio button or submit buttons seem to work, I'm also not getting the result and control back in the first activity.  (Previously, I used to be able to get a Toast on ever on checked option on the radio button, but now that doesn't seem to work either).  Trying to send the activity result aborts the application (since I added finish() to the second activity).

```
/* java */
package com.example.m.googlemapappfirst;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class InformationInputActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText editText;
String content = "";
LatLng providedLocation;

public InfoType infoType = InfoType.NO_INFO;
InformationPoint informationPoint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information_input);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
    providedLocation = bundle.getParcelable("provided_location");
    String message = String.valueOf(providedLocation);

    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);
    editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    editText.setMaxLines(5);


    Toast.makeText(this, "enter cheese info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?


    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    Toast.makeText(this,"you selected your cheese", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_information_input, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void AddPictureHandler(View view){
    Toast.makeText(this, "i like to take pictures of cheese", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void SubmitHandler(View view){
    content = editText.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, "add cheese info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(infoType == InfoType.NO_INFO){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select an Information type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(content.equals("")){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please write a description", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    informationPoint = new InformationPoint(providedLocation, infoType, content);

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    returnIntent.putExtra("information_point", informationPoint);

    this.setResult(1, returnIntent);
    finish(); /* added after original post, this makes app crash consistently */


}

}
```

Here's the xml layout file for the second activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.m.googlemapappfirst.InformationInputActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/instructions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_swiss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/swiss"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_american"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/american"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_gruyere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gruyere"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_cheddar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cheddar"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>

<TextView android:text="@string/instructions2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/type_here"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:maxLines ="4"
    android:maxLength ="2000"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    />


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take_picture_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Picture"
        android:onClick="AddPictureHandler" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Report Information"
        android:onClick="SubmitHandler" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well in your second activity you forget to add listener to your buttons. And can you give us the stacktrace from crash of your app ?

Comment: I am new to coding for Android, how do I get a stack trace?  All I get is "Unfortunately, Cheese Map App has closed, "  Only button shown is "Force clsoe".  (RUnning on device, emulator doesn't work on AMD laptop.)

Comment: You can see the logs of your app in the logcat. You can access this in different way depending of your IDE (or even command line). In this view you will see a lot of messages and for any uncaught exception (like the one causing your app to crash) a stack trace

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to review the logcat.  The problem was with serializing the InformationPoint - I ended up sending the 3 members individually and that worked.
I've been struggling with logcat quitye a bit -- I can't get a logcat from the Alcatel OneTouch Evolve I am using to test.  I could get a logcat fine from an old Samsung Galaxy 4G 2 with Cyanogenmod 12.1.

Comment: I'm posting about my problem with the logcat here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416850/cant-get-logcat-alcatel-onetouch-evolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any problem but missing invocation of show() after toast creation, just like this:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oops... This shouldn't happen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Now all the toasts are working... and indeed, I get into the submit handler, but then control won't pass back to the first activity.  (I'll edit the code above to add the show() as per your recommendation.)

Comment: You're welcome. It happened to me sometime, you may care about this always. Android studio also adds a warning "missing .show()"