# Can't get LogCat (Alcatel OneTouch Evolve)

Tags: android-studio, logcat, android-logcat, alcatel-ot

I've been trying to debug an application using my Alcatel OneTouch Evolve running "Firmware Version 4.1.2" (I guess that's Android Jellybean 4.1.2) but I get an empty logcat, and I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2. Debugging works just fine with another device (Samsung Exhibit 4G 2 running CyanogenMod 12.1 -- Lollipop), but it's excruciatingly slow. This suggests that my computer's setup is fine for debugging but that something is wrong with the Alcatel OneTouch's settings.

Has anyone else seen this? Or have a suggestion for how to get logcat running for this device?

Comment: Have you enabled debugging over USB for that device in its settings?

Comment: Yes. I've enabled debugging

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue with this device. Running `adb logcat` from the terminal gave no logs for the Alcatel OneTouch Evolve, but this command worked for other devices.

Running `adb logcat *:V`, I was able to see logs on the Alcatel OneTouch Evolve as expected. This uses a more verbose filterspec than the default, `*:I`.